# Webgl flickering signal when translating continuously

Tags: webgl

I'm building some signal monitor where points are received through a websocket connection and displayed as an "oscilloscope signal", ie: latest point is always on the right of the screen, older points travel to the left.

To achieve this effect, I apply a new translation matrix every time the webgl buffer is drawn.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epz98mdv/

dataset is an array of vertices, 1 point per ms

```js
const dataset = [[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[2,0,0] ... [15822,0,0],[15823,0,0]]
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var gl = gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {
      preserveDrawingBuffer: false,
      antialias: false
});
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
gl.lineWidth(1);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

var projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
var scaleMatrix = mat4.create();
var modelMatrix = mat4.create();
var translationMatrix = mat4.create();

mat4.ortho(
  projectionMatrix,
  0,
  1,
  0,
  1,
  0,
  1
);

mat4.translate(
  translationMatrix, 
  translationMatrix, 
  [
    2,
    1,
    0,
    0]
);

mat4.scale(
  scaleMatrix, 
  scaleMatrix, 
  [
    calculateScaleFactor(),
    calculateAmplitudeFactor(),
    1
  ]
);

var fShader = createShader(
  gl,
  gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER,
  getFragmentShader()
);
var vShader = createShader(
  gl,
  gl.VERTEX_SHADER,
  getVertexShader()
);

var program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program, vShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fShader);

gl.linkProgram(program);
if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
  console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(program));
}

var vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(
  program,
  "a_position"
);

var scaleMatrixPosition = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_scaleMatrix");
var translationMatrixPosition = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translationMatrix");
var projectionMatrixPosition = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_projectionMatrix");
var modelMatrixPosition = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_modelMatrix");
var uFragColor = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_fragColor");


var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

gl.bufferData(
  gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
  new Float32Array(1000000),
  gl.STATIC_DRAW
);


var verticesPendingBuffering = new Float32Array(100000);
var numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering = 0;
var lastVerticeIndexInVertexBuffer = 0;

feedData(0);

function draw() {

  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  if (numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering > 0) {

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);

    gl.bufferSubData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      lastVerticeIndexInVertexBuffer * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
      verticesPendingBuffering.subarray(0, numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering)
    );
    lastVerticeIndexInVertexBuffer += numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering - 3;

    mat4.translate(
      translationMatrix, 
      translationMatrix, 
      [
        -0.004,
        0,
        0,
        0]
    );

    numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering = 0;

  }

  gl.useProgram(program);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(scaleMatrixPosition, false, scaleMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(translationMatrixPosition, false, translationMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixPosition, false, projectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixPosition, false, modelMatrix);

  gl.uniform4fv(uFragColor, [ 1/255 , 255/255 , 255/255 , 1.0]);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    vertexPositionAttribute,
    3,
    gl.FLOAT,
    false,
    0,
    0
  );

  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, lastVerticeIndexInVertexBuffer / 3);

  requestAnimationFrame(() => draw())
}

requestAnimationFrame(() => draw())

function createShader(gl, type, str) {

  let shader = gl.createShader(type);

  gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
  gl.compileShader(shader);

  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  }

  return shader;

}

function getVertexShader() {
  return `
  attribute vec3 a_position;
    
  uniform mat4 u_translationMatrix;
  uniform mat4 u_scaleMatrix;
  uniform mat4 u_modelMatrix;
  uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;

  void main(void) {

    vec3 pos = a_position;
          
    vec4 scaled_position = u_modelMatrix * u_scaleMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);

    gl_Position = u_translationMatrix * u_projectionMatrix * u_modelMatrix * scaled_position;

  }
`;

}

function getFragmentShader() {
  return `

    precision mediump float;
    uniform vec4 u_fragColor;

    void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = u_fragColor;
    }
  `;

}

function calculateScaleFactor() {

  var mmToPx = 1/document.getElementById('mmpx').getBoundingClientRect().width;
  var windowWidthInMm = canvas.width * mmToPx
  const pointsPerSecond = (windowWidthInMm / 50);
  let displayRateScaleFactor = 1 / parseInt(pointsPerSecond * 1000);

  return displayRateScaleFactor;
}

function calculateAmplitudeFactor() {
  return 70 / (canvas.height * 4);
}

function feedData(pos) {

  var i;

  for(i = pos; i < pos + 20 && i < dataset.length; i++) {
    verticesPendingBuffering.set(dataset[i], numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering);
    numberOfVerticesPendingBuffering += dataset[i].length;  
  }

  setTimeout(() => feedData(i), 20)

}
```

Any idea what might cause this?